# Should I use R=301 on redirect that doesn't change URL?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have converted some pages into SEO-friendly URLs.

Old format:

```
mydomain.com/myscript.php?f=1&t=2
```

New format:

```
mydomain.com/f1-t2-some-stuff-tagged-on.html
```

Because I have some stuff tagged on to the URL, this redirect is done in php where stuff tagged on requires a bit of logic and processing.  End result, I get a URL that I'm happy with.

To process the new format, I've created a rewrite rule which ensures the new format gets process by myscript.  It looks like this:

```
RewriteRule ^f([0-9]+)-t([0-9]+)(.*)$ myscript.php?f=$1&t=$2&friendly=1 [NC,L]
```

This works well.  It doesn't change the URL in the browser but does execute myscript.php and renders the page.  Note, I added a variable 'friendly' to tell the php script not to redirect to the friendly version, but just render the page.

This all works great.  I'm sure there are more elegant solutions, but I'm happy with this and most importantly IT WORKS.

So my question is:  I want to specify that the new format is permanent (ie 301 redirect).  Where should I specify this?  In the php redirect from old format to the new format?  Or in the .htaccess rewrite that doesnt' change the URL?  I'm thinking the former but thought I would check with you guys.

Answer (score 2):

The PHP redirection (from old to new format) **is** a permanent one. You don't wan't anybody to use the old URL, then you need to add this header :

```
header('Status: 301 Moved Permanently', false, 301);
```

The `.htaccess` redirection (from new format to the real URL) is a transparent one. This is the URL you want to be indexed, so you must not specify `[R=301]`. If you do, the redirection stops to be transparent, and your URL change.

Comment: Bang on. Thats exactly the answer I was looking (and hoping) for. You rock.